# I am having trouble with provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, mobileprovision

I am following the directions in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlOdp4uZoo

Up until 6:05, I am pretty sure I followed his directions correctly. However, when I double-clicked on the newly downloaded **mobileprovision** file, it didn't open (OS X and Xcode are up to date). I spent some time researching the problem and decided to move the file to `*~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`. The next problem was with the code signing. At 7:35, he fills in the provisioning profile section in the project Built Settings with the newly created provisioning profile. However, when I used mine, when I tried to archive the project, there was an error which said:

> "Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “0b58edbf-733c-4701-9de9-5d4907d86ada”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.".

The error was gone and the project archived successfully when I used the **iOS Team Provisioning Profile** instead of the one I just created. However, I am afraid this isn't going to get me far since in the video, he uses the new provisioning profile again in various places. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you have a `0b58edbf-733c-4701-9de9-5d4907d86ada.mobileprovision` in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Xcode -> preferences -> accounts, select your Apple ID account, select your team on the right hand panel, then go to view details, there you should be able to download all provisioning profiles to their necessary location.